# Custom table sql scripts not loading magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Here is my config and Model classes.

I have changed the version number in both the config and sql installer.

But still the custom table doesnt seem to be added in core_resource table.

Where am i wrong?

```
 <config>
 <modules>
    <Vendor_Recipe>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </Vendor_Recipe>
</modules>
<global>
     <resources>
        <vendor_recipe_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Vendor_Recipe</module>
                <class>vendor_Recipe_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </vendor_recipe_setup>
    </resources>

    <models>
        <vendor_recipe>
            <class>Vendor_Recipe_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vendor_recipe_resource</resourceModel>
        </vendor_recipe>

        <vendor_recipe_resource>
            <class>Vendor_Recipe_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                   <spen_recipe>    
                        <table>spen_recipe</table>
                    </spen_recipe>
             </entities>
        </vendor_recipe_resource>

     </models>
   </global>
    ....
```

**Vendor\Recipe\sql\vendor_recipe_setup\install-1.0.1.php**

```
<?php

 $installer = $this;

 $installer->startSetup();

 $table = $installer->getConnection()
->newTable($installer->getTable('vendor_recipe/spen_recipe'))
->addColumn('vendor_recipe/recipe_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'identity'  => true,
    'unsigned'  => true,
    'nullable'  => false,
    'primary'   => true,
    ), 'Recipe ID')
->addColumn('vendor_recipe/user_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'USer ID');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

**vendor\Recipe\Model\SpenRecipe.php**

```
<?php
class vendor_Recipe_Model_SpenRecipe extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('vendor_recipe/spen_recipe');
    }
}
```

**\Recipe\Model\Resource\SpenRecipe.php**

```
<?php

class vendor_Recipe_Model_Resource_SpenRecipe extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
 {
   protected function _construct()
  {
    $this->_init('vendor_recipe/spen_recipe', 'recipe_id');
  }
}
```

**\Recipe\Model\Resource\SpenRecipe\Collection.php**

```
<?php
class vendor_Recipe_Model_Resource_SpenRecipe_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('vendor_recipe/spen_recipe');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@QaisarSatti mysql keyword is necessary but for `magento 1.8` or previous version.
from magento1.9 onwards you can create setup class or you can use default setup class. and you dont have to write mysql before your script filename

for that you have to change your resource node like below .

```
<resources>
    <vendor_recipe_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Vendor_Recipe</module>
            <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class> <!--or your  setup class -->    
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </vendor_recipe_setup>
    <vendor_recipe_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </vendor_recipe_write>
    <vendor_recipe_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </vendor_recipe_read>
</resources>
```

**or**
 you can create your own setup class and extend this core class to this and provide your own class to resource setup node

```
<?php 
class Vendor_Recipe_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
{  

}
?>
```

**And also there is a mistake in your**

`Recipe\Model\Resource\SpenRecipe\Collection.php` file

class name should be

```
   `Vendor_Recipe_Model_Resource_SpenRecipe_Collection`
```

instead

```
  `vendor_Recipe_Model_Resource_SpenRecipe_Collection`
```

**and your folder name to should be `Vendor` not `vendor`**

and also 
`Recipe\Model\Resource\SpenRecipe.php`

class name should be

```
`class Vendor_Recipe_Model_Resource_SpenRecipe`
```

not 
    `class vendor_Recipe_Model_Resource_SpenRecipe`

and also `Vendor\Recipe\Model\SpenRecipe.php` file

class name should be `class Vendor_Recipe_Model_SpenRecipe`  not  `class vendor_Recipe_Model_SpenRecipe`

And also change your `config.xml` accordingly

```
     <config>
 <modules>
    <Vendor_Recipe>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </Vendor_Recipe>
</modules>
<global>
     <resources>
        <vendor_recipe_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Vendor_Recipe</module>
                <class>Vendor_Recipe_Model_Resource_Setup</class> <!-- V change -->
            </setup>
        </vendor_recipe_setup>
    </resources>

    <models>
        <vendor_recipe>
            <class>Vendor_Recipe_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vendor_recipe_resource</resourceModel>
        </vendor_recipe>

        <vendor_recipe_resource>
            <class>Vendor_Recipe_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                   <spen_recipe>    
                        <table>spen_recipe</table>
                    </spen_recipe>
             </entities>
        </vendor_recipe_resource>

     </models>
   </global>
```

Comment: change in layout by adding <connection> worked, thanks